# Is it possible to "share" google photo shared albums without making it public for everyone?

Tags: google-photos

Shared Albums in Google Photos seem like a good idea. For example, if me and my friends all go to the same party, I can create a shared album with them and suddenly, they can see my photos of the event too.

However, it seems the only security for who can view a shared album is in knowing the URL. Is it possible to specify exactly who can view my shared albums? Something similar to google docs, where you can grant access to certain users only.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not seem possible with the current version of Google Photos.

I recommend you suggest a feature by:

1. Opening the google Photos app or going to photos.google.com
2. At the top left, touch or click the menu icon [image: Menu Icon]> **Help & Feedback** (or **Send Feedback**)
3. Touch or click **Feedback**.

Source: [How to get feature requests/feedback to the Google Photos team](https://sites.google.com/site/picasaresources/Home/Picasa-FAQ/google-photos-1/how-to/how-to-get-feature-requests-feedback-to-the-google-photos-team)